# jquery $.post json dataType response

Tags: jquery, ajax

im trying to process response from $.post in json format.

```
    $("#contactform").submit(function() {
    var a = $(this).attr("action");
    $("#message").slideUp(750, function() {

        $("#message").hide();
        $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $.post(a, 
            {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                comments: $("#comments").val()
            }, function(data) {

                alert(data.status);                 

            }
            ,{ dataType: "json" }
        );
    });
    return false;
});
```

the response from the ajax comes in just fine. and even if it take out ,{ dataType: "json" } line and just alert('data'); everything is working just fine. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what's your problem. What's not working?

Comment: oh sorry. i get no errors in the console but the alert does not come up.

Comment: Is the returned JSON valid ? please post what the ajax returns.

Comment: {"status":"fail","msg":"<ul><li>Enter your name.<\/li><li>You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.<\/li><li>Enter your message.<\/li><\/ul>"}

Comment: i use php json_encode, so it should be valid

Comment: Try to add a `done` function (`$.post().done()`) intead of `success` param. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Because your alert doesn't show up and you have no console errors, It seems your success callback isn't fired.

Add an error callback and then you might find your response status code is not 200.

Plus, the dataType parameter should be a string:

```
   $.post(a, {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            comments: $("#comments").val()
        }, function(data) {
            alert(data.status);
        }
        , "json")
        .fail(function() {
          alert( "error" );
        });
```

If you have an error, check the Network tab in `Chrome Development Tools` to see the exact response..

Answer (score -1):

I normally use `$.ajax` where data type is specified  as `{ dataType: "json" }`.
Now in `$.post` you just state type as a string `"json"` that is what was failing the response.